# nw.js protect every .js file with nwjc tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js

Is this possible to protect all files in project with [nwjc](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Protect-JavaScript-source-code-with-v8-snapshot#sample-for-nwjc) tool and then package all this with nw-builder for example ?

Why this function only works with one file ? Official site says that they fixed performance issue in 0.22, but why there is no tool to protect all project files and include them like in `index.html`:

`require('nw.gui').Window.get().evalNWBin(null, 'app/mytest.bin');`

Comment: You should define project as JavaScript actually lacks notions of a project outside of conventions such as "a directory containing a package.json" file. Regardless, I assume you can build a bundle, with something like Gulp, Grunt, JSPM, Webpack, or Browserify and then pass the bundle to nwjc. A bundle can be as simple as the concatenation of a number of files or as complex as a combination of modules transpiled, processed, composed, and aliased along with resource files such as css and html transformed into strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found better way, i use grunt and with [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) tool compile all my project to one file, then with nwjc protect this file and include it to html. Works nice and i guess even faster because on 0.22 was fixed performance issue

Answer (score 0):

NWJC only compiles JS into native code. It will never touch your HTML.

If your concern is security for proprietary code, you could use a tool like [Enigma VB](http://enigmaprotector.com/en/aboutvb.html) to consolidate your code into a single executable.